# Which music plays in episode 126 on Android 17 vs Toopo?

Tags: music, dragon-ball-super

I was watching episode 126 - "Surpass Even A God! Vegeta's Desperate Blow!!" of *Dragon Ball Super* on Crunchyroll. I want to know the music that plays when Android 17 is about to fight with Toppo god of destruction after saving Freiza.

Episode time when that music plays: 4:35 to 6:10

Episode link: http://www.crunchyroll.com/dragon-ball-super/episode-126-surpass-even-a-god-vegetas-desperate-blow-760341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual soundtrack that plays is - Strongarm Battle, DISC 2, Dragon Ball Super Original Soundtrack Vol.2. You can check that here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhqzFhTyLCg

Comment: Thank you I wonder why I couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more search I found it. Its the "Theme of Gohan" by Norihito Sumitomo.
Can't find the original OST but there is a recreation which is quite close to it by a guy named "PokeMixr92"on Youtube.
Here is the link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guuVnTQavSc

Answer (score 0):

It's "Theme of Android 17". Gohan's is very similar, just kinda different.

Here is the song recreated by PokeMirx92 on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRR2TJLbfgY)

Comment: unfortunately its not the one. hear the music in the episode and the one in the link i shared you will see why its not the one you shared